# Rails AJAX select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am trying to have an AJAX event for a `<select>` box that will do some action when the selection changes. The select box is embedded inside inside a table's `<td>` tags

```
<td>
  <%= form_tag '', { :id => 'test_form' } do %>
    <select name='repo' value="<%= session[:repo] %>" >
      <option></option>
        <%@repos.sort! { |a,b| a.repo <=> b.repo }
          @repos.each do |r| %>
            <option <%= session[:repo]==r.repo ? "selected='repo'" : '' %>>
              <%=URI.escape(r.repo)%>
            </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
  <% end %>

  <%= observe_form( 'test_form', :frequency => 2, 
  :update => 'update_results', 
  :url => {:action => :update_report, :page => 0, :update => 1 }, 
  :loading => "$('res_spin').show()", :complete => "$('res_spin').hide()" ) %>
</td>
```

I have embedded the select box in a form and the `observe_form` method to listen for a selection change. My controller function is `update_report` that will do something when the selection changes. For some reason, when the selection changes, the controller function is not getting called at all.

Turned on "Firebug" and seeing this error a lot of times

```
    $(form) is null
    var elements = $(form).getElementsByTagName('*'),
```

Comment: To nail down where the issue is I would suggest commenting out all the logic and just have an on click event that shows a pop up box.  This shows you the listener is working.  If that works then something is wrong with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[observe_field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field)** (as discussed [here](http://www.plexusweb.com/staff/charlie/blog/post/302/Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-using-ObserveField)):

`<%= observe_field(:state, :url => { :action => :update_report, :page => 0, :update => 1 },
                  :update => :update_results,
                  :with => 'repo'
            ) %>`

Comment: Still does not work. Interestingly, I am using the same code somewhere else and it works just fine. The only difference here is that the form_tag is embedded with the <td> tags.

Comment: Can you post the output? I think something is wrong with your form tag.

Comment: ah ha. there is no form tag in the html output. I only see the <td> tags and inside that there is no form tag. Why is that?

Comment: Get rid of the '=' sign in the <%= form_tag ... %>